Advice: Worldbuilding Parsimony
Ever since the movie Interstellar and the TV show The Expanse worldbuilders have been on a nearly non-stop quest for the most realistic fantasy worlds possible. This frequently leads to silly questions as worldbuilders dream up the most amazing things and then ask to crowbar them into Real Life.
Part of the problem is an astounding belief that science can actually predict or explain everything. I'll be honest with you, the belief is almost as good as a religion. But other than to mention it as a contributing factor to the issue, I don't want to distract you, dear reader, any more because of it.
The truth is, good worldbuilding is a balance between detail and summary; facts and fiction. There's a sweet spot between "I can explain everything about this" and "this is complete fantasy" where imagination encourages suspension of disbelief on the point of "what if?" But that balance is difficult to explain to a rising generation that wants to measure the distance from the wall in nanometers to drive a nail of specific metallurgical quality with exactly right right weight of hammer into the one substance that can possibly accept the nail.
Sometimes, chasing the details, while fun, is an exercise in futility because the rabbit hole of Real Life is a whole lot deeper than most people realize. So...
Question: How do we explain worldbuilding parsimony to new worldbuilders?

The cause may be a lack of trust of their intended audience and the incorrect belief that, having a scientific explanation is necessary or sufficient to avoid criticism. In actuality people need to seriously love the work to waste their time doing a deep analysis of any worldbuilding inconsistencies. Good worldbuilding just isn't about having a scientific backing for everything. Good worldbuilding can be fantastic, and completely detached from real world physics. Explaining the fantastic, tells instead of shows, and renders the fantasy mundane.

If I look at some fiction I have recently read, where the world itself captured my imagination, most don't explain a thing. The City and the City, Peridido Street Station and This is How You Loose the Time War all had worlds that left me wanting more.. None of them attempt to scientifically justify a thing. In fact I'd argue any explanation increases the surface where bad worldbuilding could impact the reader. It's easy accept that some critter teleports. Just tell us that's how things work. If you explain how, the explanation also gets scrutinized. Is it really worth it to you?

Stephenson is an exception but not everyone enjoys chapter long obsessively researched tangents on say 16th century German silver mining that do nothing to further the plot.

@sphennings Dude.... why wasn't that an answer?

In the vein of leading by example, The Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy is a marvelous showcase of flabbergasting worldbuilding where science has been taken into a back alley and tied to the gutter pipe while the author created his world in peace.
Nothing of that trilogy in five books would have been written like it has been if it had to be under the blade of science.

My copy of the Hitchiker's Guide came with a foreword by Douglas Adams. The part that stuck out to me is that he described making the audio show first, then writing the book that contradicted it, then writing more books contradicting themselves, finally writing the movie which also contradict the audio show and the books. The series thrives on this.

Sounds like something PTerry would have said. I am proud of you Dutch!

@elemtilas speaking of, Terry Pratchett has a book from before the Discworld series. It's called "Strata" and it's the first time in his works where a disc-shaped world appears. The setting there is on the harder sci-fi end and by all accounts it's not scientifically possible to have such a world. Yet it exists. That does turn into a plot point.

@VLAZ -- Indeed! That too is a great read! In any sufficiently well described universe, you're bound to find all kinds of scientifically impossible things!

There are several different schools of thought on how to handle this.
The first is to merely state something is, and then let the reader fill in the blanks. This is the old-school method, IMO, whereby a Technology is asserted to exist, it's function is described and the Reader or consumer of the content has to be left happy with this. Things like Shields in the original Star Wars - We have no idea how they worked - only that they existed. They are, for all intents and purposes, inconsequential to the key plot.
The only time that shields are relevant to the main plot is on the Death Stars exhaust port - we are told "The shaft is ray shielded, so you'll have to use proton torpedoes."
Do we know what is meant by Ray Shielding? No.
Do we know why Proton Torpedoes are immune to this sort of Shielding? No.
And yet - it works in both a World building sense and a narrative sense.
This is hard for World Builders who like to have everything planned out - but so long as they are internally consistent, you can just simply state something is - and be done with it.
In this example - Simply stating something as a matter of fact and moving on can do more from a world building sense, than trying to explain every little detail - sometimes less is more, because the empty space invites the readers imagination to fill in the blanks
The next option is to give a cursory Nod to real world physics and problems:
My Go-To example is the Heisenberg Compensator in Star Trek: Link - a very quick and dirty physics lesson - the more accurate you make a subatomic particles speed, the less accurate you make its position and vice versa.
It effectively means that a Teleporter (in the way that Star Trek conceives of it) cannot work... And so how to address this from a World Building perspective - Simple! Just add a McGuffin that deals with it.
And it is such an elegant solution - it is even named after the very problem. Do we get a lengthy Trekno-babble explanation of it - Nope, and we don't need to. We are told that there is a component that solves this problem and the viewer is happy with that.
In this method, we acknowledge a real-world problem - state that there is a technological work-around for it and be done with it - it has elements that are more elegant thant the Star Wars method - in that it acknowledges the real world, whilst still making impossible tech sound plausible
The last method, is perhaps the most fun and the most difficult to do:
Anything is possible, so long as it is internally consistent. Oh look, it is time for me to reference Warhammer 40K.
I love WH40K - but it is very very very silly (part of the reason I love it) - And one of the silliest and most fun parts of WH40K is the Orks. Orks have a lot of lore - but the part that is relevant here is how their technology works - when it appears to be just a ramshackle collection of bits thrown together... It works because the Orks create a psychic field that makes it work because they believe it works - and thus, every single design decision can be justified as working under that rubric - it is a masterpiece of internal consistency.
If you have the right rules and stick to them, even the most absurd and stupid things can work within your world.
Now, it does require a lot of buy-in from the reader (and WH40K has surrounding lore that helps justify why the Ork Psychic field can have a manifest impact in the real world) - but done right, you can have whatever the hell you like, with complete disregard for Physics, mechanics or anything - so long as there is an internally consistent justification for it.

On the Orks' thing - that is a perfect way for fantasy to work, and in particular I think 40K did a really good job describing why it works. I read a book once, A Deadly Education I believe, that was that way too; there is a school of magic that's constructed in a completely-unphysical and architecturally-impossible way, but it's built in a metaphysical void in which believing something worked made it work, and the school had its technical diagrams and maps spread all over the place to encourage the students to think about it working so that it'd work. No real science, wonderful story.

I'm bookmarking this answer to remind me when I get stuck how I can present something.

There's a sweet spot between "I can explain everything about this" and "this is complete fantasy" where imagination encourages suspension of disbelief on the point of "what if?"
There isn't any such universal sweet spot. There are as many sweet spots are there are authors, each with their individual style of story telling.
At one end you have authors like Stanisław Lem, whose stories are more in the nature of philosophical fables, offering very little detail about the world in which the stories take place; for example, his famous novel Solaris (1961), where literally nothing is explained. The lack of explanation is actually the point. (There is a revered cinema adaptation by Andrei Tarkovsky (1972), and another very different American cinema adaptation by Steven Soderbergh (2002).)
At the other end your have authors like Jules Verne, or in more recent times Michael Crichton, who intentionally pile mountains of practical details in the construction of their worlds.

The balloons were made of a strong but light Lyons silk, coated with gutta percha. This gummy, resinous substance is absolutely water-proof, and also resists acids and gas perfectly. The silk was doubled, at the upper extremity of the oval, where most of the strain would come.Such an envelope as this could retain the inflating fluid for any length of time. It weighed half a pound per nine square feet. Hence the surface of the outside balloon being about eleven thousand six hundred square feet, its envelope weighed six hundred and fifty pounds. The envelope of the second or inner balloon, having nine thousand two hundred square feet of surface, weighed only about five hundred and ten pounds, or say eleven hundred and sixty pounds for both.(From Jules Verne's Five Weeks in a Balloon, 1863, English translation by a fictitious William Lackland, 1869.)

